# populate options for a drop down list from the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Please consider the following.This is what I have been trying to do.
1)I have a drop down list which can be used to select semesters.
2)Once I select the semester,courses for that semester should appear in another drop down list.
3)As the semester changes courses may also have to change.

My database

```
course_info(courseID varchar(15) primary key,courseName varchar(30),semester int)
```

This is what I did using ajax,php and mysql.

***My html page***

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showsemester(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","showsemester.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showsemester(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a semester:</option>
<option value="1">Y i S i</option>
<option value="2">Y i S ii</option>

</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>courses will be listed here.</b></div>
</body>
```

***My php page***

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','scifac');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


$sql="SELECT * FROM course_info WHERE semester = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>course ID</th><th>name</th><th>semester</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>". $row['courseID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['courseName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['semester'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now it produces the result in a div as a table and working properly without any errors.But I would like to take the cours names as options in a drop down list and course ID as the values.

Your kind consideration given with this regard is highly appreciated.
Thank you.
T

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to do. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't see where the problem is. You are able to get the data into a table... why can't you do the same thing with a <select>Loop here<option></option>endloop here </select>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php file code file should be like this

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','scifac');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


$sql="SELECT * FROM course_info WHERE semester = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
<select name = "semester">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['courseID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['courseName']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Where do i need to add this? to php file or html because at the very beginning i gave it should be added to the div txthint

Comment: Thank you very much.I highly appreciate your contribution.I have been trying to do this since several days.Thank you once again.